# How to select, copy and paste cell output from a Jupyter Notebook running in VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, langchain

I'm trying out LangChain in Python and have an error

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
loader = TextLoader("Scribbles.txt")
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
```

It results in an error:

```
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

As well as a load of other stuff. I want to pull out the relevant bits from what is a large cell output (in this case, a traceback) but while I can scroll through it I can't use CMD-a to simply select everything (I use Mac). And I can't scroll when I try to use mouse select.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little protracted but you can start at the top, select and using shift click the bottom of the message. Still a faff.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: there is a new `COPY` context menu command for vscode v1.82 to be released soon.

The cell output menu will have a COPY (to the clipboard) option.

Also, a cell image's context menu will have a copy option for that image.